# Best way to Dynamically add navigation menu based on User Authentication in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have multiple components like Login, Users, Clients and so on.
I want to hide the navigation before login and only after Login is successful Navigation has to be enabled.

Currently I am Adding the Navigation in all the components separately. 
That is

**Navigation for Login:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar">
            <h1>My App</h1>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
</nav>
```

**Once the login is successful**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"> Admin </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <h6> <a href="register">Register Users</a> </h6>
                    <h6> <a href="users">Display Users</a> </h6>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Why not just leave everything there and turn it on/off with a ngif?

Comment: can you share any link if you come across

Answer (score 0):

Define your `app.component` like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then define a `shell.component` like this:

```
<mh-menu></mh-menu>

<div class='container'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Anything that should be displayed without a menu can then be routed to the app.component's router outlet.

Anything that should be displayed with a menu can be routed to the shell component's router outlet.

Something like this:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: '',
            component: ShellComponent,
            children: [
                { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
                { path: 'movies', component: MovieListComponent},
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            ]
        },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ])
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

I have a more complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Answer (score 0):

First you should set the status (logged or not) then in the navbar component check for that value, and expose it to the view and with a simple *ngIf it would be all done.

```
<ul *ngIf='isLogged()' class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"> Admin </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <h6> <a href="register">Register Users</a> </h6>
                    <h6> <a href="users">Display Users</a> </h6>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```